# Windows Task Scheduler output

Tags: xml, windows, logging, scheduled-tasks

I have some executables that are to be scheduled to run with Windows Task Scheduler. They have output that must be seen somewhere. When running the apps through the Windows Task Scheduler, the output from the program is lost. How can I capture this output? I did Google and find the hack to instead run cmd and redirect the output to a log file, but I can't get that information to sit nicely in an XML file which I should be able to register with task scheduler, so I need a better way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I can't get that information to sit nicely in an XML file" - can you explain more specifically what that means? In what way does your method for redirecting to a (log) file fail to be able to create an XML file? Is it that you need to be able to append to the same XML file multiple times, and have it be a well-formed XML file after each append?

Comment: Sorry, pretty far off interpretation of the question. Windows TS has XML schema for registering tasks, one of the tags is Command and Arguments. I am trying to run the Command as 'cmd' and the Arguments as something like '/C <path to my app> <arguments to my app> >> <path to output log>.output.txt 2>&1'. The Arguments tag is complaining when I try to load it into the Windows TS...it's probably something involved with escapaing characters in the XML but I'm not sure. Here's an example:

Comment: <Command>cmd</Command>
            <Arguments>/C C:\Users\cdietsch\Documents\Development\EclipseWorkspace\TrexProjects\trex\translators\target\appassembler\bin\sunspotters.bat -i C:\Users\cdietsch\Documents\Development\HECO_Raw_Data\SunSpotters -address tcp://localhost:9090 >> C:\Users\cdietsch\Desktop\TEST.output.txt 2>&1</Arguments>

Comment: OK... Can you post a reference to a description of the hack?

Comment: Sure, here, thanks: [link](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/01/26/capture-the-output-from-a-scheduled-task/)

Comment: OK, so the hack is not described as working for the Windows TS XML Schema. The redirection part, `>> log 2>&1`, is not really part of "arguments"; it's interpreted by the cmd shell rather than processed by the program. I imagine that's why it doesn't work as part of `<Arguments>`. One reasonable workaround would be to have Windows TS execute a batch file, and have the batch file execute `c:\...\sunspotters.bat -i ... >> test.output.txt 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> OK, so the hack is not described as working for the Windows TS XML Schema. The redirection part, >> log 2>&1, is not really part of "arguments"; it's interpreted by the cmd shell rather than processed by the program. I imagine that's why it doesn't work as part of . One reasonable workaround would be to have Windows TS execute a batch file, and have the batch file execute c:...\sunspotters.bat -i ... >> test.output.txt 2>&1